# Spring AOP aspect doesn't get applied if included from an external jar with different package name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a spring boot rest service that included an external project in pom as it's dependency. That external project is basically a jar that has spring AOP code.

The base package in my main application that includes this external jar with spring AOP code is x.y.z

The class in external jar where the @before advice is, is under the package a.b.c
With this class under a.b.c package, it doesn't get recognized by the main application where I want to use the spring aop implementation and apply the aspect. However, when I change it's package from a.b.c to x.y.z (which I really can't do in real life) it works fine.

I know that in spring boot service which happens to be the including service, it scans everything under root package given in the application class, x.y.z in this case and that is why aspect works fine if it's class is under x.y.z.

however, the problem is that this spring app jar will be used across multiple applications. So changing package name like this is not an option.

Is there a way to accomplish this without changing the package name of the class where spring app code is ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably component scan is only activated for your application class packages by default. You can extend it to multiple packages, including the aspect package:

**XML style configuration:**

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z, a.b.c" />
```

**Annotation style configuration:**

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"x.y.z", "a.b.c"})
```

*Disclaimer: I am not a Spring user, only an AspectJ expert. I just knew that you can configure component scan, googled the syntax for you and hope it is correct.*

Comment: I need to refrain from this solution even though it would work because then applications that use the reusable jar need to add component scan for the package in the jar. Defeats the whole purpose of being reusable

Comment: Aspects are pretty intrusive. It is rather a feature than a limitation that you can decide to activate or deactivate them via configuration. Users have to decide to put the JAR on the classpath, so they can also activate component scan, I guess. If that's too much work for you, switch to [AspectJ with LTW (load-time weaving)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) or even weave your aspect code into the application with compile-time weaving using the AspectJ compiler.

Comment: Another thought: Logging libraries are also reusable, but they also do not work if the including app does not provide configuration. Your library would still be reusable, just not properly configured. Is a one-liner worth switching to another AOP framework? Don't get me wrong, I love AspectJ and never use Spring, so I am happy if you use it,too. But with my answer you pretty much have what you need with the tool you are currently using (Spring) and which is built into it.

Answer (score 0):

Please define the bean (of jar project )inside main application. Give the @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"x.y.z", "a.b.c"}) as well as @EnableAspectJAutoProxy. Also include below piece of code.

ex:

```
 ` @Bean
  public  LoggingHandler loggingHandler()
  {
      return new LoggingHandler();
  }`
```

Also annotate external jar code with:

```
`@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingHandler {`
```

Answer (score -1):

What @kriegaex suggests is correct. In addition to that, please make sure you are using `@Component` along with `@Aspect`. Since `@Aspect` is not a Spring annotation, Spring won't recognize it and hence your aspect won't be registered. So, using `@Component` is mandatory to getting aspects to work in Spring environment.

Comment: That solution defeats the whole purpose of creating a reusable jar if every application that uses the jar has to add a component scan for the package in the jar

Comment: Let us consider an anology. If you were to write 100 different programs showcasing 100 things that can be done using `java.lang.String`. you will have to import `java.lang.String` 100 times. Does that mean writing a String class defeats the whole purpose?

What `@CompomentScan` does is something similar.

One can put all the jars on classpath, but if spring is unaware of the them, its not going to scan for the components that are present inside.